# Automating Oracle database installation on Windows

Tags: oracle, installation

I'm trying to install an Oracle 12c database on Windows using the silent install with a response file as:

```
setup.exe -silent -responseFile file.res
```

Where I generate the response file using the GUI and placed all the passwords in it.
The installation with the same settings works using the GUI install, but the silent install has 2 problems:
1: The command exits after a few seconds while it opens another terminal installing.
The `-waitForCompletion` option does not work.
2: The installation freezes up at some point. See the log below:

```
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

 Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\OraInstall2014-03-22_02-05-24AM. Please wait ... [WARNING] [INS-3001
1] The ADMIN password entered does not conform to the Oracle recommended standards.
   CAUSE: Oracle recommends that the password entered should be at least 8 characters in length, contain at least 1 uppercase character, 1 lower case character
and 1 digit [0-9].
   ACTION: Provide a password that conforms to the Oracle recommended standards.

You can find the log of this install session at:
 C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\installActions2014-03-22_02-05-24AM.log
Dll to load is C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\OraInstall2014-03-22_02-05-24AM\Win64RunProcesses.dll
Loading psapi.dll from C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\OraInstall2014-03-22_02-05-24AM\psapi.dll
Could not copy C:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1/bin/oracle.exe to C:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1/javavm/jdk/jdk6/admin/oracle.exe
Could not copy C:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1/rdbms/admin/oracle.sym to
C:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1/javavm/jdk/jdk6/admin/oracle.sym
PersistEnv
INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\odp.net\bin\2.x\oracle.dataaccess.d
ll is registered successfully in GAC.

INFO: The following section has been added.
<section name="oracle.dataaccess.client" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConf
igurationHandler, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />


INFO: The following element added under DbProviderFactories.
<add name="ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Unmanaged Driver" type="Oracle.DataAccess
.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />

INFO: Counters registered successfully in the system.
INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\odp.net\publisherpolicy\2.x\policy.
2.102.oracle.dataaccess.dll is registered successfully in GAC.
INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\odp.net\publisherpolicy\2.x\policy.
2.111.oracle.dataaccess.dll is registered successfully in GAC.
INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\odp.net\publisherpolicy\2.x\policy.
2.112.oracle.dataaccess.dll is registered successfully in GAC.
INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\odp.net\bin\4\oracle.dataaccess.dll
 is registered successfully in GAC.
INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\odp.net\publisherpolicy\4\policy.4.112.oracle.dataaccess.dll is registered successfully in GAC.

INFO: The following section has been added.
<section name="oracle.dataaccess.client" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
b77a5c561934e089" />


INFO: The following element added under DbProviderFactories.
<add name="ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Unmanaged Driver" type="Oracle.DataAccess
.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />

INFO: Counters registered successfully in the system.
INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\asp.net\bin\2.x\oracle.web.dll is registered successfully in GAC.
INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\asp.net\publisherpolicy\2.x\policy.
2.111.oracle.web.dll is registered successfully in GAC.
INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\asp.net\publisherpolicy\2.x\policy.
2.112.oracle.web.dll is registered successfully in GAC.
INFO: Following entries added in GroupedProviders.xml file.
<MembershipProvider name="OracleMembershipProvider" /><RoleProvider name="OracleRoleProvider" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OracleMembershipProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Security.OracleMembershipProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=2.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f4
29c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="tru
e" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" pas
swordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OracleProfileProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Profile.OracleProfileProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=2.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c4734
2" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OracleRoleProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Security.OracleRoleProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=2.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" co
nnectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OracleSiteMapProvider" type="Oracle.Web.SiteMap.OracleSiteMapProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=2.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c4734
2" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OraclePersonalizationProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Personalization.OraclePersonalizationProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=2.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, Public
KeyToken=89b483f429c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OracleWebEventProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Management.OracleWebEventProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=2.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429
c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" buffer="true" bufferMode="OracleNotification" />
Connection string name OraAspNetConString is set successfully

INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\asp.net\bin\4\oracle.web.dll is reg
istered successfully in GAC.
INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\asp.net\publisherpolicy\4\policy.4.
112.oracle.web.dll is registered successfully in GAC.
INFO: Following entries added in GroupedProviders.xml file.
<MembershipProvider name="OracleMembershipProvider" /><RoleProvider name="OracleRoleProvider" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OracleMembershipProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Security.OracleMembershipProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f4
29c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="tru
e" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" pas
swordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OracleProfileProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Profile.OracleProfileProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c4734
2" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OracleRoleProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Security.OracleRoleProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" co
nnectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OracleSiteMapProvider" type="Oracle.Web.SiteMap.OracleSiteMapProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c4734
2" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OraclePersonalizationProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Personalization.OraclePersonalizationProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, Public
KeyToken=89b483f429c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" />

INFO: Following entry added to machine.config file.
<add name="OracleWebEventProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Management.OracleWebEventProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429
c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" buffer="true" bufferMode="OracleNotification" />
Connection string name OraAspNetConString is set successfully

INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\ode.net\bin\2.x\oracle.database.extensions.dll is registered successfully in GAC.
INFO: c:\oracle\mike\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\ode.net\bin\4\oracle.database.extensions.dll is registered successfully in GAC.
ERROR: Cannot add user to application access ACL.
No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
(534)
ERROR: Cannot add user to application launch ACL.
No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
(534)
```

Comment: Not a solution but for info - That error appears to be a Windows Error message related to version problems. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890737

Comment: What version of Windows are you installing on?

Comment: This specific error was on windows server 2012 c12 database.

Comment: Are you running setup from an elevated (run as administrator) or standard cmd prompt? If not elevated, try that.

Answer (score 1):

**ERROR**

> Cannot add user to application access ACL.  No mapping between account
>   names and security IDs was done.

**CAUSE**

This is because when you are installing Oracle for the first time, the group ORA_DBA is not already existing and is created later during the installation.

**SOLUTION**

Ignore the message and continue the installation.You will not get the message when installation is done for the second time.

Comment: Seems like the OP is trying to the install without having to do it twice... any better solution available?

Comment: Create the ORA_DBA group in advance?